# Browser issue with css background image, not showing perfectly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing browser issue in displaying background image. Images used as CSS is not showing perfectly in Google Chrome. Tried with Everything, but nothing worked.

Link is: http://j.lookten.com/

### More Description:

I have used background from CSS in "TOGETHER WE CAN DO MORE" and "TOGETHER WE CAN DO MORE" section of page, but the background is not supported by Chrome. This works perfectly in Firefox. I want to make it work in Chrome too.

Any Suggestion???

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the issue?

Comment: A "something's not working" question is too general. Either attach a screenshot with the problem or give a much more accurate description.

Comment: I have used background from CSS in "TOGETHER WE CAN DO MORE" and "TOGETHER WE CAN DO MORE" section of page, but the background is not supported by Chrome. This works perfectly in Firefox. I want to make it work in Chrome too.

Comment: I checked with chrome and ff and they both show the background the same way without any problems. What's not working?

Comment: Its not working in chrome as it does in Firefox. Also In chrome when you scroll the page up and down, the background disappears. And sometime even it is having problem to display initially here.

Comment: I get a fixed positioned background image on both browsers. My chrome version is 31 and FF is 26. Maybe you're using older versions?

Comment: My chrome version is "Version 34.0.1847.131" but still not working perfectly for Parallax effect image..

Answer (score 1):

You declared background-size: 100% in the same selector? Just remove that and keep these background-size rules. Somehow Chrome was not applying the rule correctly because of the double declaration?

```
.divider { /* It is how single divider look's */
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think to say at PARALLAX effect?

inspects the console have 2 errors not loading:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://j.lookten.com/assets/css/bootstrap.css.map

instead. jquery.min.js: 5 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://j.lookten.com/assets/js/jquery.min.map

this happen in chrome